# Execution failed for task 'CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an Android app with android target: android-22
I also tried with android-17

but this error message appear.

```
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavacC:\Users\Luis Araujo\Desktop\myApp2\platfor
 ms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:222:erro
r: cannot find symbol
    getActivity().requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
                 ^

^



* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUIL D FAILED

Total time: 24.973 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\Luis Araujo\Des
ktop\myApp2\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\Luis Araujo\De
sktop\myApp2\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.
useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

I installed API 23 of the Android SDK, and I let in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and the `property.properties` the target android-23

Then, type `ionic build android` and `ionic run android`